Почему обращение на "вы" появилось только в XVIII веке, но при этом было сохранено обращение на "ты"?

Считается, что раньше формы на ВЫ  встречались  в дипломатической переписке (XV век)  и  только по отношению  к русским царям в таких выражениях, как  ваше господство,  к вашей милости, к вашей высокости и т.д.  В XVIII веке,  в Петровскую эпоху,  вежливое обращение на  Вы стало  уже международной этикетной формой и из области дипломатии проникло в другие сферы официального и  даже неофициального общения русских людей. Из статьи.

Для сравнения: В английском языке все наоборот, обращение на ТЫ постепенно ушло из языка и сейчас используется в частных случаях.
— Для нас, изучающих английский язык, отсутствие 
 обращения на “ты” и “вы” большой-пребольшой 
 плюс! Меньше головной боли!

— Ну, это как сказать! При переводе сонетов 
Шекспира все наоборот. К тому же у тех, кто 
изучает русский язык, головной боли как раз 
хватает)


Можно ли объяснить, почему был заимствован международный этикет на ВЫ, но при этом сохранено обращение на ТЫ?  Это особенности нашего языка или русской ментальности?


